# How to write a regex that matches duplicated words with 5 occurrences?

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I want to match the duplicated words which in this instance is **GHL_AutoMatchFaulted**
In this example, there are 5 occurrences which I want to match all 5 otherwise it will not match

```
GHL_AutoMatchFaulted
GHL_AutoMatchFaulted
GHL_AutoMatchFaulted
GHL_AutoMatchFaulted
GHL_AutoMatchFaulted
```

Is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Tried almost all from the forum but nothing works.

Comment: I've edited your post because you wrote the entries on seperate lines, but they were showing up on one line. That difference is significant for working with regex. If they are actually on one line, undo the edit or say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one: ?

```
(GHL_AutoMatchFaulted\s?\n?){5}
```

- Looks for the keyword `GHL_AutoMatchFaulted`
- with an *optional* space `\s?`
- and an *optional* carriage return `\n?`
- for exactly 5 times `{5}`

As per [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NtTSTi/1):

- it will match 5 replicates in a row,
- but **not** 4 replicates in a row.
- however it will match the **first 5 replicates** when there are 6 replicates in a row.

[image: Regex101]

Comment: Presumably the regex needs to work for any arbitrary 5 word duplications.